# Oracle Database connectivity issue with C# and Delphi-7

Tags: c#, oracle10g, delphi-7

Windows form application build in C# is unable to fetch the data from Oracle database without Oracle Client installed on the system, whereas the same exe build with Delphi7 platform + ODAC fetches data from Oracle without Oracle Client installed.
Can anyone explain the reason??

Comment: Are you sure Oracle Client isn't installed? It might be that you only have 32-bit client installed, for example, while the C# application runs as 64-bit. And there's alternate libraries that don't require the Oracle Client, of course.

Comment: @Luaan, Which library I should use with C#? Let me clarify you- Delphi-7 is installed on my PC with ODAC, and my application is compiled by using ORA.dcu and is running on client's PC without installing Oracle Client on that PC. My C# application is using oracle-client.dll and running fine on my PC and one of my Client PC where I installed Oracle Client but it is not running on the PC where Oracle Client is not installed. This is not feasible solution to install Oracle Client on each client's PC. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Connection with Delphi may be possible since it will be using BDE or Third party component like ToracleSession,TOraSession . These components do not require Oracle client installation.
Refer Following link for example --

- https://www.devart.com/odac/faq.html

Comment: Can you give example of C# that fulfil the above condition.. Yes the Delphi code is using Torasession

Answer (score 0):

Refer Below link to connect to oracle without using oracle client.

https://begeeben.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/accessing-oracle-database-without-installing-oracle-client/